# Plotting a variable over time with sudden change

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a value of variable  over time. X is the time where each value of Y shows the value of the variable at that time. Time is divided into seconds, so I keep track of the variable value each second and I record that into a CSV file. However if you see that there's a sudden change in the variable value from zero to a high value. I want to plot that behavior
where the sudden change is also visible in the plot, i.e I want to see a line connected from zero to the sudden change. How can I do this in R? I want the plot to be a line plot not a dot plot, i.e. all points are connected.

[image: Size overtime]

Comment: probably, the data should be missing at that point; otherwise it should connect the dots

Comment: You're asking how to do a line plot in R?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply with this command:
plot(x,y, type="l")